# While Loop: Challenge for beginners

Tags: while-loop

Challenge:

Use a while loop to increment count by 2 on each repetition of the block of code. Run the code block of your while loop until count is 8

let count = 2;

---

I just started learning code two days ago, I am not really sure the logic behind what it is I should do, when to use a while loop or logically the difference between that and an infinite loop. I would really appreciate any help

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please say what language you are using, and add the corresponding tag to your question.  But also keep in mind that this site is not really for help getting started; you can get direct answers to direct questions, but if you want step-by-step help through a problem, you should look elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You call while with a condition, in your case while count < 8.

Inside your while loop you increment count by two every iteration until it is 8 or bigger. So it would look like this:

```
let count = 2;

while (count < 8) {
    count = count + 2;
}
```

When the condition is not true, so when your count is equal or bigger than 8, the inner part of the while loop is not being executed (your while loop terminates).

An example for an infinite while loop would be with the condition "true":

```
while (true) {
    ...
}
```